# Sentiment analysis does not handle neturals

Tags: python, transformer, bert, sentiment-analysis

I'm writing some financial tools,  I've found highly performant models for question and answering but when it comes to sentiment analysis I haven't found anything that good.  I'm trying to use huggingface:

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis')
print(classifier("i'm good"))
print(classifier("i'm bad")) 
print(classifier("i'm neutral"))
print(classifier("i'm okay")) 
print(classifier("i'm indifferent"))
```

Which returns results

> [{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.999841034412384}]

> [{'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.9997877478599548}]

> [{'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.999396026134491}]

> [{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9998164772987366}]

> [{'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.9997762441635132}]

The scores for all of the neutral words come up very high in a positive or negative direction,  I would of figured the model would put the score lower.

I've looked at some of the more [fine-tuned models](https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english) yet they seem to perform the same.

I would assume there would be some pretrained models which could handle these use cases.  If not, How can I find neutral sentiments?

Comment: I closed this post because it seems you were mainly interested in a programming solution to your problem (given the accepted answer). However, if this was a conceptual question, i.e. you were interested in the approach rather than implementation, then let me know and I could re-open this post.

Comment: @nbro, I was fine with conceptually or programmatically, but you can leave this closed since I already found an answer which met my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can try Spacy. Here you go.

```
import spacy 
from spacytextblob.spacytextblob import SpacyTextBlob

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') 
spacy_text_blob = SpacyTextBlob() 
nlp.add_pipe(spacy_text_blob)

text = "i'm good" 
doc = nlp(text) 
print(doc._.sentiment.polarity) # 0.7

text = "i'm bad"  
doc = nlp(text) 
print(doc._.sentiment.polarity) # -0.6999999999999998

text = "i'm neutral" 
doc = nlp(text) 
print(doc._.sentiment.polarity) # 0.0

text = "i'm okay"  
doc = nlp(text) 
print(doc._.sentiment.polarity) # 0.5

text = "i'm indifferent"  
doc = nlp(text) 
print(doc._.sentiment.polarity) # 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising, I just need a few hours to check it out when im off work and then ill accept the answer!